# Align ListView or Datagrid Header Vertically VS2005 C#

Tags: c#

I have the following listview with default format.

[image]

I want to align datagrid or listview  headers in vertical manner rather than existing horizontal way.

```
Earning      001                003          002           
Earning Name Salese Comission   OPD Bills    Direct Supply
```

Help me please

Comment: User "eagle" posts a nice snippet here to pivot a datagrid.  Some people even say it works!  http://www.justskins.com/forums/pivot-a-datagrid-140713.html

Comment: You want to swap rows and columns. Need to do it in code. This is not just aligning them..

Comment: how to? any idea..